# vif(): "Warning message: No intercept: vifs may not be sensible." Trying to check multicollinearity with multinomial logistic regression

Tags: r, nnet, multicollinearity

I am trying to create a multinomial logistic regression model using `nnet::multinom()`. I have 2 independent variables (numeric from 0 to 10) and a dependent variable (factor with 4 levels 1,2,3,4).

The problem is that when checking for multicollinearity with `vif()` function from `car`, I get the following warning:

`Warning message: No intercept: vifs may not be sensible.`

Here is some example code:

```
set.seed(150)
example <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:10,1000,rep=TRUE)))

example$dependent <- factor(sample(1:4, 1000, rep=TRUE))

example$dependent <- levels(relevel(example$dependent, ref = "1"))

mymod <- multinom(dependent~., data=example)

vifs <- vif(mymod)
vifs
```

output:

```
  X1       X2 
 5.297042 5.257941
```

This gives reasonable values, however with my actual data they range from 2.289297e^1 to 5.609178e^15.

Any advice? I don't understand the message saying there's no intercept, because I thought intercept is automatically in the model unless you remove it.