# VIF No intercept: vifs may not be sensible

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, multinomial

I am trying to test that the assumption of my Multinomial Logistic Regression model holds or fails.

Multinomial Logistic Regression model is a model which could be created and compared, although it has this assumption:

> Multinomial logistic regression does have assumptions, such as the
> assumption of independence among the dependent variable choices. This
> assumption states that the choice of or membership in one category is
> not related to the choice or membership of another category (i.e., the
> dependent variable). ([source](http://You%20can%20use%20the%20iris%20dataset%20for%20the%20purpose%20of%20experimenting.))

So after searching for a while I came across variance inflation factors which measure how much the behavior (variance) of an independent variable is influenced, or inflated, by its interaction/correlation with the other independent variables.

```
#Multinomial Logisitic Regression
mlrModel = train(
  label~.,
  data = overallDataset,
  method = "multinom",
  trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5),
  trace = FALSE
)
mlrModel$results
head(predict(mlrModel, type = "prob"))
library(car)
vif(mlrModel$finalModel)
```

But I get this warning:

```
Warning message:
In vif.default(mlrModel$finalModel) :
  No intercept: vifs may not be sensible.
```

And the results varied massively: 8.575035e+07 to -7.188586e+13

I have not removed the intercept from the model.

I found this question: [vif(): "Warning message: No intercept: vifs may not be sensible." Trying to check multicollinearity with multinomial logistic regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281481/vif-warning-message-no-intercept-vifs-may-not-be-sensible-trying-to-chec) but it had no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in what have quoted, note that it says "Multinomial logistic regression does have assumptions, such as the assumption of independence among the **dependent variable choices**." When you look for variance inflation factor, you are looking at multicollinearity between **independent variables** . I don't quite see the connection here.

There is an intercept in the multinomial model. But you need to remember there are more than 1 set of coefficients, if there are n classes in your labels, one of them is treated as the intercept and you have n-1 set of coefficients.

Hence you see that error, because in the `vif` function called (car:::vif.default), there is a line in the code:

```
if (names(coefficients(mod)[1]) == "(Intercept)") {
        v <- v[-1, -1]
        assign <- assign[-1]
    }
    else warning("No intercept: vifs may not be sensible.")
```

So, we can use an example below to demonstrate why it returns the error:

```
library(nnet)
fit = multinom(Species ~.,data=iris)
vif(fit)
 Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length   Petal.Width 
-1.878714e+16 -8.846005e+15 -1.827592e+15 -4.954974e+15 
Warning message:
In vif.default(fit) : No intercept: vifs may not be sensible.
```

Same error, and we look at the coefficients:

```
coefficients(fit)
           (Intercept) Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
versicolor    18.69037    -5.458424   -8.707401     14.24477   -3.097684
virginica    -23.83628    -7.923634  -15.370769     23.65978   15.135301

names(coefficients(fit))
NULL
```

Because it is multinomial, the coefficients are stored as a matrix (using one class as reference, you estimate log-odds of other classes), hence the names() function doesn't work, and returns you the error.

There might not be an easy method or way to calculate the vif for a multinomial model, without diving deep into the statistics, what I suggest below is a rough approximation using logistic on the difference classes:

```
labels = rownames(coefficients(fit))
ref = set.diff(fit$lab,labels)
t(sapply(labels,function(i){
       dat = iris
       dat$Species = as.numeric(dat$Species == i)
       vif(glm(Species ~ .,data=dat,family="binomial"))
}))

           Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
versicolor     6.860029    1.511153    27.926317   14.795556
virginica      1.624657    2.797563     1.985489    3.093114
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what the improved solution is doing/how it's working. Why are we using binomial now instead of multinomial? @StupidWolf

Comment: You cannot use `vif()` on a the multinomial from nnet, it is not meant for that. A workaround, if you want to look at multi collinearity within a multi nomial model, is to do two separate logistic regression, like what I have done above

Comment: This should give you a close approximation